# Sometimes Meteor screen freezes/cannot scroll

Tags: meteor

Sometimes, (more often than not), the browser screen freezes while navigating through a Meteor app. Basically everything works fine but I cannot scroll up or down.

There are no JS errors and everything seems to be running ok.

What could be causing htis?

Comment: Probably something in your code

Comment: have you figured something out ?

Answer (score 0):

This is often a hard thing to debug, but the first things I'd do are :

1. Disable your CSS (sometimes the silliest things can seem disasterous)
2. Check that there are no errors, in your terminal either (Meteor logs to the browser and terminal)
3. could you be flooding the front end with data?  how big are your collections? are you using auto-publish or neatly crafted pub/subs?
4. What packages have you included in your project?  try disabling any non essential packages
5. Install [Kadira](https://kadira.io/), and monitor your performance

Its really hard without more information, off the top of my head I imagine that you're either experiencing some weird styling / rendering issue, or that you're waiting on oversized subscriptions.  Meteor overall should feel quite fluid and quick.  I have a few questions :

1. Can you share more information about your app or where you're experiencing the issues you've described?
2. Is your project available anywhere?
3. What Browser are you viewing it in?
4. localhost or on a server? (if so what server environment?)